# Hold Values in Objects for back navigation UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, navigation, template10

I am working on a Template 10 MVVM based UWP application.

### Current Scenario

I am getting the data from an `api` and creating a local `IEnumerable` property named `HugeDataConsumer` on the `viewModel`.

### What's happening:

After `navigation`, to another view, when I press back and comeback to my `mainView`, the `HugeDataConsumer` `IEnumerable` becomes null because the `ViewModel` is created again.

### what I want to achieve:

I want my `ViewModel` to hold the value of the `HugeDataConsumer` IEnumerable so that the navigation back event feels like a state resumed. 
I have tried setting the  `NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Required;` on my codeBehind, but I don't think it applies to my `viewModel` as well. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually serialize your data using DataContractSerializer and deserialize it back when you navigate to the main view model. [Prism](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism) is using a service called SessionStateService to do such things.

NavigationCacheMode does not apply to the context. It only cashes the view itself, not the model.

You can always cache your data using your own static classes but I think everybody will agree with me if I say developers hate static classes.

Also, if you are developing a UWP app do not forget the suspension scenarios. Whenever your app gets suspended your OnNavigatedTo will fired with a NavigationMode Refresh parameter when the user gets back to the app.

Comment: That's a great answer. Although I solved the issue using `navigationCache` but then I had no option other than that than to use a static calss